# What is the difference between explicit and implicit mapping in SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, kernel-trick, pattern-recognition

1) What is the difference between explicit and implicit mapping
2) What is the difference between mapping and kernel trick?

Answer (score 2):

When talking about the kernel trick the mapping is referred to as *implicit* because we are not mapping the actual instances in the data to the kernel-induced feature space. For training a support vector machine, it does not matter to us *how* the new feature space looks and where our data lies within it - we only need to know the inner product of our instance's images in that space.

Given a kernel function $K$ satisfies [Mercer's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem#Mercer's_condition), it can be expressed as the inner product in the kernel-induced feature space

$$K(x_1,x_2) = \langle\phi(x_1),\phi(x_2)\rangle$$

where $\phi$ is a mapping into a [hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) $\mathcal F 
 $
$$\phi:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}.$$

A kernel function like the [Gaussian RBF kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel) acts as a similarity measure of our instances in the original feature space and also fulfills Mercer's condition.